# Create own encoding

Tags: ruby, encoding

How can I create my own encoding in Ruby (1.9)?  The encoding would be for converting string while reading/writing from/for a file, i.e. generally for manipulating data in nonstandard encoded strings ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazovia_encoding )

Comment: What kind of encoding? Character encoding?

Answer (score 1):

To your updated question: At the moment all you can do is write some custom code which handles file reading/writing at byte level and does the needed conversions.

---

If you refer to how you can use different character encodings in ruby with version 1.9 I point you to

[Working with Encodings in Ruby 1.9](http://blog.nuclearsquid.com/writings/ruby-1-9-encodings) and

[Understanding M17n](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/understanding_m17n)

Comment: he ment implementing an Encoding instance for an Encoding that is unsupported by default on ruby

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any references in the ruby-docs about using proprietary encodings, and the `Encoding` class doesn't have any initializers (but `Encoding.find()` can load some of the encodings `IConv` supports dynamically) Unfortunately afaik `Mazovia` is unsupported even in `iconv`, so you're stuck with implementing your own class...